# How to share a session values between an ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two projects:

1. ASP.NET webforms (.NET 4.8)
2. ASP.NET Core Web API (.NET 6.0)

There are many session values which are used by the ASP.NET webforms app. Since the ASP.NET Core Web API application would be running side-by-side, I need to access these session values in the .NET Core project, too.

I followed the instruction given in

[Session sharing between Asp.Net Webforms and Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73638526/session-sharing-between-asp-net-webforms-and-asp-net-core)

but I got `Null` values in the .NET Core Web API project every time.

Here is my code snippet for the ASP.NET application

`Web.config`:

I have installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters` and `Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState`:

[image]

`Global.asax`:

[image]

Setting a session value:

[image]

Changes made to the ASP.NET Core Web API:

`Program.cs`:

[image]

`appsettings.json`:

[image]

Code to retrieve the session value:

[image]

Let me know if I am missing anything here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am checking [the source code here](https://github.com/mjrousos/UpgradeSample/tree/b4cddc2aae4957fa4fa2d72e8f32ecf34d356538/Incremental/12-Start), and [this is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_XG3EYRcgY8).

#### Please quick test, first

Please open the `Contact.aspx` page first, make sure the  code  `Session["Test"] = "Hello World";` was excuted.

#### My Suggestions

The sample code your provided I found 2 issues, but your asp.net web application could be working well and youe asp.net core web app should get error  like below

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Test
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
```

Please change it and check it works or not.

*In ASP.NET Global.asax.cs*

Change

```
.AddJsonSessionSerializer(options =>
                {
                    // Serialization/deserialization requires each session key to be registered to a type
                    options.RegisterKey<string>("Test");
                    options.KnownKeys.Add("Test", typeof(string));
                })
```

to

```
.AddJsonSessionSerializer(options =>
                {
                    // Serialization/deserialization requires each session key to be registered to a type
                    options.RegisterKey<string>("Test");
                    //options.KnownKeys.Add("Test", typeof(string));
                })
```

*In ASP.NET Core Program.cs*

Change

```
.AddJsonSessionSerializer(options =>
    {
        options.RegisterKey<string>("Test");
        options.KnownKeys.Add("Test", typeof(string));
        
    })
```

to

```
.AddJsonSessionSerializer(options =>
    {
        //options.RegisterKey<string>("Test");
        options.KnownKeys.Add("Test", typeof(string));
    })
```

**The package in my project.**

Asp.net core

[image]

Asp.net

[image]

If it still not works, [please share a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that I could help you.

Comment: i made the changes you asked but still no luck. i have put my sample code at https://github.com/AijazChauhan/SessionShare
please check and let me know if i am missing out there

Comment: please review the code from link i have shared i above comment

Comment: Hi @AijazChauhan ， will check it tomorrow

Comment: Hi @AijazChauhan, I have compared the two repos, my working on is using asp.net core mvc, yours is swagger api. I think this should be the expected behavior because [APIs are stateless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3105337/7687666)

Comment: It make sense to me as well. Thank you @JasonPan for your efforts

Comment: @AijazChauhan If my findings useful to you,could you accept it as answer,tks, have a nice day